# notifydataSetChanged on Adapter will update with new items, but will not update the existing items

Tags: java, android

I could not find something specifically relating to my exact issue, please read on to find out what that is.

I took great care to make sure that everywhere in my code, I am set up right to just call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter, I initialize the itemList once, and pass that to the adapter, and don't re-initialize it ever.

It works like a charm, and the list view will update itself, but only for new items.

For existing items, the ListView will not update correctly.

For example if I have a listview that is displaying some custom items, and I need to update it I do this

```
public void updateList(List<item> newItems)
{
    if (adapter == null)
    {
        itemList.addAll(newItems);
        adapter = new SomeAdapter(layoutInflator, itemList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else
    {
        // lets find all the duplicates and do all the updating
        List<item> nonDuplicateItems = new ArrayList<item>();
        for (Item newItem : newItems)
        {
            boolean isDuplicate = false;
            for (Item oldItem : itemList)
            {
                // are these the same item?
                if (newItem.id == oldItem.id)
                {
                    isDuplicate = true;
                    // update the item
                    olditem.text1 = newItem.text1;
                    oldItem.text2 = newItem.text2;
                }
            }

            if (isDuplicate == false)
            {
                // add the new item
                nonDuplicateItems.add(newItem);
            }
        }

        // I have tried just adding these new ones to itemList, 
        // but that doesnt seem to make the listview update the
        // views for the old ones, so I thought thuis might help
        // by clearing, merging, and then adding back
        nonDuplicateItems.addAll(itemList);
        itemList.clear();
        itemList.addAll(nonDuplicateItems);

        // finally notify the adapter/listview
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

now the listview will always update to show new items, but it will not update the views on the existing items.

Here is the real kicker that tells me it is an issue with the views: if I call `adapter.getItem(position);` on a updated pre-existing item, the item returned will show the updated changes, (meaning text1 and text2 will hold their new values) even though it is not reflected in the listview!

If I call `listView.invalidateViews();` then the list view will show the updates, but I have two problems with that, sometimes it flickers, and sometimes, just sometimes if I call it and it runs before the `notifyDataSetChanged` can finish getting through to the listview, I get a "List view not notified of data change" error!

Does anyone know anything about this?

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.item_comment, null);
                    // when the holder is created it will find the child views
                    // it will then call refreshHolder() on itself
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView, position);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else
        {
            viewHolder = ((ViewHolder) convertView.getTag());
            viewHolder.refreshHolder(position);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

public void refreshHolder(int position)
{
    this.position = position;
    tvText1.setText(getItem(position).text1);
    tvText2.setText(getItem(position).text2);
}
```

I wonder if what I should do is re-instantiate all my items before adding the to the list, using a copy constructor. Perhaps when notifying the adapter, the adapter will assume there is no changes if the `item` is still the same reference, and so will not redraw that view? or perhaps the adapter only draws new views for new items when notified?

To add another detail, if I scroll down making the updated view go off screen, and then come back to it, it displays the correct info as the listview refreshes/remakes that view.

I guess I am needing the listview to refresh all its current views so, `invalidateViews();` may be what I have to do.

Does anyone know more about this?

EDIT:
As requested here is an adapter that would have this issue.

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    private final static int VIEWTYPE_PIC = 1;
    private final static int VIEWTYPE_NOPIC = 0;

    public List<Item> items;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflator;
    ActivityMain activity;

    public ItemAdapter(List<Item> items, LayoutInflater layoutInflator, ActivityMain activity)
    {
        super();
        this.items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        updateItemList(items);
        this.layoutInflator = layoutInflator;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void updateItemList(List<Item> updatedItems)
    {
        if (updatedItems != null && updatedItems.size() > 0)
        {
            // FIND ALL THE DUPLICATES AND UPDATE IF NESSICARY
            List<Item> nonDuplicateItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
            for (Item newItem : updatedItems)
            {
                boolean isDuplicate = false;
                for (Item oldItem : items)
                {
                    if (oldItem.getId().equals(newItem.getId()))
                    {
                        // IF IT IS A DUPLICATE, UPDATE THE EXISTING ONE
                        oldItem.update(newItem);
                        isDuplicate = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // IF IT IS NOT A DUPLICATE, ADD IT TO THE NON-DUPLICATE LIST
                if (isDuplicate == false)
                {
                    nonDuplicateItems.add(newItem);
                }
            }

            // MERGE
            nonDuplicateItems.addAll(items);
            // SORT
            Collections.sort(nonDuplicateItems, new Item.ItemOrderComparator());
            // CLEAR
            this.items.clear();
            // ADD BACK IN
            this.items.addAll(nonDuplicateItems);
            // REFRESH
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void removeItem(Item item)
    {
        items.remove(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        if (items == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Item getItem(int position)
    {
        if (items == null || position > getCount())
            return null;
        else
            return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return getItem(position).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        Item item = getItem(position);
        if (item.getPhotoURL() != null && URLUtil.isValidUrl(item.getPhotoURL()) == true)
        {
            return VIEWTYPE_PIC;
        }
        return VIEWTYPE_NOPIC;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ItemHolder itemHolder;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEWTYPE_PIC)
            {
                convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.item_pic, null);
            } else
            {
                convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            }
                    // THIS CONSTRUCTOR ALSO CALLS REFRESH ON THE HOLDER FOR US
            itemHolder = new ItemHolder(convertView, position);
            convertView.setTag(itemHolder);
        } else
        {
            itemHolder = ((ItemHolder) convertView.getTag());
            itemHolder.refreshHolder(position);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (getCount() < 1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Ok I have now tried this

```
    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return getItem(position).hashCode();
    }
```

and this

```
    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return getItem(position).hashCode();
    }
```

where my hashcode is a reflection builder from apache used like so (Should work cause the hash changes based on values)

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
    }
```

and it didn't work. From what I can tell stableIds is doing nothing.

EDIT:

none of these work either, in any combination of stable Ids. Once again, and the same as always, you have to scroll the view offscreen and then back on in order for it to be updated.

```
listview.refreshDrawableState();
listview.requestLayout();
listview.invalidateViews();
```

Comment: Please post the code of the Adpter. The `ViewHolder`is a common pattern used enhance performance. It does not have inpact on your issue.

Comment: I know very well what a ViewHolder is, the point of me showing that is because as I have said before, the issue lies in when I call notifyDataSetChanged, the currently visible items do not get updated until you scroll down, and then back up. The underlying data changes, and everything works as expected except for this. I showed the ViewHOlder, because one might ask why is my item not getting visually updated? and I wanted to eliminate my way of implementing getView() as an issue. It has a very impactful purpose when you ask why a view is not getting updated with the new underlying information.

Comment: You can try to change the viewHolder that contains every child view of the convertView. I think the viewHolder prevents the view from re-inflate the entier view instead of its children.

Comment: @Sripathi Why should that be? The viewholder only optimizes the search for childviews by "caching" the references.

Comment: Yes, but using holder for the children will prevent re-inflating the children views not entire view. But now you are using holder for the entire view so there may be a chance to prevent re-inflating the entire row view right? Thats the problem in your case I believe. Try and let me know your result.

Comment: That would be interesting, I will give it a try (I'm not to sure about it though, but if it works I will eat my words), as well as the ids solution from AlexS.

Comment: @WIllJBD I am facing a similar issue in my case I am highlight an item after user interaction. The highlight works for the current item but another item down in the list at random position is also highlighted for your case I guess invalidating the listview first then setting the new adapter and notifydatasetchanged will certainly work.

Comment: @WIllJBD I think you forgot to set stableIds to true in your update: The first two examples are identical.

Comment: oh haha, I forgot to change it, I was just copy pasting

Comment: @WIllJBD Check my answer pls, I hope it works for you, despite the downvotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a similar issue here with a solution that may work:

[ListView not refreshing already-visible items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635220/listview-not-refreshing-already-visible-items)

Comment: Could you please tell me the reason of the downvotes?

Comment: @WIllJBD I guess I can do nothing about the downvotes, so I ask you to consider my answer in case it solves your problem. It's the same as Ginger Head's, and I posted it hours before him. I hope it's just a coincidence that his answer got upvoted, and in the same time mine got downvoted, despite the fact the two answer is basically same.

Comment: I am sorry that this happened, is is basically the same, not sure why it got downvoted, I gave you an upvote to offset the unfairness. Although in your example you did the same thing I did and told me to do different by the comments, maybe they overlooked that?

Comment: the method refreshHolder() is called inside the constructor of the ItemHolder, this is why I give it the position in the constrcutor. Unfortunately this isn't it either. :( The issue is not with my code, it is with the way ListView and the Adapter interact. I have been going through the code in the SDK, and I believe that notifyDataSetChanged, although necessary to let the listview know the dataset has changed, does not actually make the listview refresh its current drawable state. This is my issue, and I believe I should be able to fix is by calling refreshdrawablestate.

Comment: Well, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635220/listview-not-refreshing-already-visible-items

Comment: That looks very promising, make that your answer. I'll try it out, and if it ends up working you'll have the answer ;)

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to remove all items from the list, notify, then add the new items to the list, and finally notify again. Its much simpler to imlement, and should work.

Comment: You need to make you answer the referral. As it stands your answer is wrong, but the comment worked. I would like to accept your comment as the answer (the one referring me to build a custom listview.)

Comment: Well, I had to accept your edit, and I did it. I don't understand the reason of the rollback. Now I rolled back to your edit.

Answer (score 3):

With "unstable IDs" everything should be fine if calling `notifyDatasetChanged ()`, but it seems your `ListView` doesn't know that some existing items have to be updated.

Perhaps you can try to implement stable ids and misuse them in a way, that the id changes on item updates.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return getItem(position).getId();
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}
```

Another "brute force" approach would be to build a new Adapter and set the new adapter for the ListView.

Comment: I tried having stable id's set to true. My understanding of this is that the stable id should tell the listview when a item is the same item and does not need to be updated. So if the item at position 1 has a stable id that does not change, item 1 will not be refreshed. if the stable id does change, it will be refreshed because a new item is tehere according to the new id. is this correct?

Comment: @WIllJBD I think as well that this is the way it should work. Unfortunately this is how you do it right now, so I would try to "misuse" the stable ids as a test.

Comment: Unfortunately if you see my updated answer it didn't work. I am not sure stableIds is actually even doing anything at all. I even tried to break it. No luck.

Comment: @WIllJBD Have you tried to use a new adapter like I also suggested in my answer?

Comment: I haven't, but in all the documentation and google videos I've seen they say not to do that xD, although that is how I used to do it a while ago. If I was being lazy I would do it with a new adapter, but I am trying to do it the 'right' way. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I analyzed the code and the problem you are into and I came to the following conclusion:

The `refreshHolder` method is only invoked when the `convertView` object has a value in the heap.

That implies that when `convertView` is not assigned to any value, no update will happen.

A solution for this is to move `itemHolder.refreshHolder(position)` out of the if-else condition block that you have inserted into.

Answer (score 1):

the **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** should do the JOB, what you need to make sure is if the List itemsList you are manipulating outside the Adapter is the exact same instance that the Adapter is holding internally. If the notifyDataSetChanged() isn't working for you, that is definitely the case.

Your adapter might also be holding a 'copy' of the list you provided in the constructor, so your changes on the original list won't be reflected...maybe you can introduce a method to the adapter like: 
        **adapter.setItems(List items)** to ensure the items are really set

You don't need to call invalidateViews() on a ListView...all you need to do is make sure the Adapter has the correct list to display and trigger **notifyDataSetChanged()**.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply, The List is managed inside the adapter. It is created one time in the constructor, and any time the List is modified, it is through `.add()` or `.addAll()` or `.clear()` or `.remove()` the notifydatasetchanged does work as I said above, but it does not update the views currently visible in the list view, until you scroll away and then back. This is for updated existing items, for new or additional items that did not exist before, they are created and show/behave just fine.

Answer (score 1):

instead of :

```
@Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {
        return 2;
    }
```

Try :

```
@Override
        public int getViewTypeCount()
        {
            return getCount();
        }
```

and instead of putting

```
ViewHolder viewHolder;
```

in a getivew() method, try to put it in a starting of class before class constructor

Comment: Hmmm, this particular function is referencing the number of the type of different views (or different layouts that are being inflated), in the list view. For example if you have items in a listview look one way when they include a picture, and a different way when they don't, then you should have 2 different layouts that represent this. The list view asks for this so it can know how to better manage the convertview that you get inside of the getView() function of the adapter. Unfortunately this isn't the answer to my issue :(

Comment: the `getViewTypeCount` suggestion  would f**k the view recycler completely!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `convertView.set/getTag()` , why not directly update the views

```
refreshHolder(convertView, position);

void refreshHolder(View v, int position)
{
     ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.Text1)).setText(getItem(position).text1);
     ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.Text2)).setText(getItem(position).text2);
}
```

setTag/getTag will not be consistent on `convertView` as you are reusing the views, and same view will be reused when a view scrolled out of view and will return wrong `ViewHolder`. So most of the times the view is not updated

Comment: Actually android takes this into account, and will always return the correct recycled view, based upon the view you inflated last for that item type, and the item type of the next view.

Comment: ViewHolder is one of the standard patterns used in android to smooth scrolling of ListViews by reducing the findById-calls to a minimum. See [Android ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, this is what worked.

```
public class AutoRefreshListView extends ListView
{
    public AutoRefreshListView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public AutoRefreshListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AutoRefreshListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private DataSetObserver mDataSetObserver = new AdapterDataSetObserver();
    private ListAdapter mAdapter;

    class AdapterDataSetObserver extends DataSetObserver
    {
        @Override
        public void onChanged()
        {
            super.onChanged();
            Log.d("AutoRefreshListView", "onChanged");
            refreshVisibleViews();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated()
        {
            super.onInvalidated();
            Log.d("AutoRefreshListView", "onInvalidated");
            refreshVisibleViews();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter)
    {
        super.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (mAdapter != null)
        {
            mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        }
        mAdapter = adapter;
        mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
    }

    public void refreshVisibleViews()
    {
        Log.d("AutoRefreshListView", "refresh");
        if (mAdapter != null)
        {
            for (int i = getFirstVisiblePosition(); i <= getLastVisiblePosition(); i++)
            {
                final int dataPosition = i - getHeaderViewsCount();
                final int childPosition = i - getFirstVisiblePosition();
                if (dataPosition >= 0 && dataPosition < mAdapter.getCount() && getChildAt(childPosition) != null)
                {
                    Log.d("AutoRefreshListView", "onInvalidated -> Refreshing view (data=" + dataPosition + ",child=" + childPosition + ")");
                    mAdapter.getView(dataPosition, getChildAt(childPosition), AutoRefreshListView.this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the solution is from here

[ListView not refreshing already-visible items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635220/listview-not-refreshing-already-visible-items)

found by Kupsef

Answer (score 0):

or you can do it in this way:`listadapter.clear(); listadapter.addAll(yourData);`