# Recylerview items that are visible are not getting updated when notifyDataSetChanged() is called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I am having a recycler view whose vies of the items that are visible are not getting updated, when notifyDataSetChanged() is called. The items that are invisible are getting updated without any problem.

I have seen that this has been a problem with listview as given here:
[List view  not refreshing already visible items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635220/listview-not-refreshing-already-visible-items)

But I am not knowing what to do with recycler view.
In my recycler view adapter I add views dynamically according to my code.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class Nearby_Viewpager_Stops extends Fragment {

private final String TAG = "Nearby Stops";
View mRootview = null;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
MKLoader mProgressBar;
Context mContext;
TextView mNoStopsTV;
Nearby_Stops_Adapter mStops_adapter;
List<BusArrivalPOJO> mBusArrivalPOJOList = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<BusArrivalPOJO>> mBusArrivalDetailsPOJOList = new ArrayList<>();
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
Handler mHandler;
Handler mHandlerForOnStop;

boolean resumed = true;
private static final int REFRESH_TIME = 30;
int lengthOfStopsList;

boolean isNoStops_available_nearby = false;
boolean isFirstTimeCalled;
boolean isRunningFirstTime;


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (mRootview == null) {
        mRootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nearby_viewpager_stops, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mRootview.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mProgressBar = (MKLoader) mRootview.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mNoStopsTV = (TextView) mRootview.findViewById(R.id.no_nearby_stops_text);
    }

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mStops_adapter = new Nearby_Stops_Adapter(mBusArrivalPOJOList, mBusArrivalDetailsPOJOList);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mStops_adapter);

    return mRootview;
}


private class GetNearbyStops extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        isNoStops_available_nearby = false;
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mBusArrivalPOJOList.clear();
        pos = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        mStops_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String urlString = "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/StopPoint?radius=2000&stopTypes=NaptanRailStation,NaptanBusCoachStation,NaptanFerryPort,NaptanPublicBusCoachTram&useStopPointHierarchy=true" +
                "&modes=bus&lat="+ Constants.latitude+"&lon="+Constants.longitude+"&categories=facility&app_id=" + Constants.app_id_tfl + "&app_key=" + Constants.app_key_tfl;

        Log.v(TAG, urlString);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String line;
        InputStream inputStream;
        StringBuilder json_result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(2000);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                json_result.append(line);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        getDataFromJSON(json_result.toString());
        return null;
    }

    private void getDataFromJSON(String json) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray stopPoints = jsonObject.getJSONArray("stopPoints");

            if (stopPoints.length() <= 20 && stopPoints.length() != 0) {
                lengthOfStopsList = stopPoints.length();
            } else if (stopPoints.length() == 0) {
                lengthOfStopsList = 0;
                isNoStops_available_nearby = true;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i< lengthOfStopsList; i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = stopPoints.getJSONObject(i);
                int distance = Math.round(jsonObject1.getInt("distance")/60);
                Double lat = jsonObject1.getDouble("lat");
                Double lon = jsonObject1.getDouble("lon");
                String commonName = jsonObject1.getString("commonName");


                JSONArray lineGroup = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("lineGroup");
                new GetBusArrivals().execute(lineGroup, new LatLng(lat, lon), distance);

                String naptanID;

                for (int j=0; j< lineGroup.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject  jsonObject2 = lineGroup.getJSONObject(j);
                    if (jsonObject2.has("naptanIdReference")) {
                        naptanID = jsonObject2.getString("naptanIdReference");
                        BusArrivalPOJO busArrivalPOJO = new
                                BusArrivalPOJO(commonName, distance, new LatLng(lat, lon), naptanID);
                        mBusArrivalPOJOList.add(busArrivalPOJO);
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mStops_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            if (getActivity()!=null)
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new GetNearbyStops().execute();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (isNoStops_available_nearby) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mNoStopsTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mNoStopsTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}

int pos;
private class GetBusArrivals extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {

    /**
     * It represents the position of the first visible position of recycler view
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (isFirstTimeCalled) {
            if (getActivity() != null)
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mBusArrivalDetailsPOJOList.clear();
                    mStops_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            isFirstTimeCalled = false;
        }

    }
    LatLng latLng;
    String stopID;
    int distance;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... strings) {

        JSONArray lineGroup = (JSONArray) strings[0];
        latLng = (LatLng) strings[1];
        distance = (int) strings[2];


        try {
            for (int j=0; j< lineGroup.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject  jsonObject2 = lineGroup.getJSONObject(j);
                if (jsonObject2.has("naptanIdReference")) {
                    stopID = jsonObject2.getString("naptanIdReference");
                    String urlString = "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/StopPoint/"+stopID+"/Arrivals?app_id="
                            + Constants.app_id_tfl + "&app_key=" + Constants.app_key_tfl;
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

                    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
                    String line;
                    InputStream inputStream;
                    StringBuilder json_result = new StringBuilder();
                    try {
                        Log.v(TAG, urlString);
                        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
                        URL url = new URL(urlString);
                        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(2000);
                        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
                        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            json_result.append(line);
                        }
                        List<BusArrivalPOJO>  busArrivalPOJOs = getDataFromJSON(json_result.toString(), latLng, distance);
                        if (busArrivalPOJOs != null) {
                            mBusArrivalDetailsPOJOList.add(busArrivalPOJOs);
                            Log.v("length", "leng"+mBusArrivalDetailsPOJOList.size());
                            if (getActivity() != null) {
                                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                                            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                        if (mBusArrivalDetailsPOJOList.size() < 5) {
                                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mStops_adapter);
                                        } else
                                               mStops_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                });
                            }



                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                            j= j-1;
                    } finally {
                        if (urlConnection != null) {
                            urlConnection.disconnect();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }



        return null;
    }

    private List<BusArrivalPOJO> getDataFromJSON(String json, LatLng latLng, int distance) {
        List<BusArrivalPOJO> busArrivalPOJOList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Log.v(TAG,  json);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
            for (int i=0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                if (jsonObject.has("exceptionType") && jsonObject.getString("exceptionType").contentEquals("EntityNotFoundException")) {
                   return null;
                } else {
                    String lineName = jsonObject.getString("lineName");
                    String platformName = jsonObject.getString("platformName");
                    String destinationName = jsonObject.getString("destinationName");
                    int timeToArrivalToStation = jsonObject.getInt("timeToStation");
                    String stationName = jsonObject.getString("stationName");
                    String naptanId = jsonObject.getString("naptanId");

                    BusArrivalPOJO busArrivalPOJO = new BusArrivalPOJO(lineName, platformName, destinationName,
                            timeToArrivalToStation, stationName, latLng, distance, naptanId);
                    busArrivalPOJOList.add(busArrivalPOJO);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return busArrivalPOJOList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);


        if (pos< mBusArrivalPOJOList.size()-5 && mBusArrivalPOJOList.size()-5 == mBusArrivalDetailsPOJOList.size()
                || mBusArrivalDetailsPOJOList.size() == mBusArrivalPOJOList.size()) {
        }

        if (MainActivity.menuItem != null && MainActivity.menuItem.getActionView() != null) {
            MainActivity.menuItem.getActionView().clearAnimation();
            MainActivity.menuItem.setActionView(null);
        }
    }

}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mHandler = new Handler();
    resumed = true;
    isRunningFirstTime = true;

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isFirstTimeCalled = true;
            new GetNearbyStops().execute();

            mHandler.postDelayed(this, REFRESH_TIME * 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
}
```

**Here is the code for my recycler view adapter:**

```
class Nearby_Stops_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private List<List<BusArrivalPOJO>> mBusArrivalPOJOListFullDetails = new ArrayList<>();
private List<BusArrivalPOJO> mBusArrivalPOJOList = new ArrayList<>();

Context mContext;
private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
private static HashSet<String> isRemainingTimesOpen = new HashSet<>();

private final String TAG = "NearbyStopsAda";

Nearby_Stops_Adapter(List<BusArrivalPOJO> busArrivalPOJOList,List<List<BusArrivalPOJO>> busArrivalPOJOList1 ) {
    mBusArrivalPOJOList = busArrivalPOJOList;
    mBusArrivalPOJOListFullDetails = busArrivalPOJOList1;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rootView =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.nearby_stops_adapter,parent,false);
    mContext = parent.getContext();

    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
    TextView mStationName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stationName);
    mStationName.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-medium", Typeface.NORMAL));

    MKLoader progressBar = (MKLoader) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    TextView timeToWalkToStation = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.timeToTravel);
    CardView cardView = (CardView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

    return new Nearby_Stops_Adapter.ViewHolder(rootView, mStationName, timeToWalkToStation, cardView, progressBar);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (mBusArrivalPOJOList.size() > 0) {
        ((ViewHolder) holder).stationNameTV.setText(mBusArrivalPOJOList.get(position).getStationName());
        String time = mBusArrivalPOJOList.get(position).getTimeToWalkToStation() + " min";
        ((ViewHolder) holder).timeToWalkToStation.setText(time);
    }

    if (mBusArrivalPOJOListFullDetails.size()>0) {
        mLinearLayout.removeAllViews();

        for (int a=0; a< mBusArrivalPOJOListFullDetails.size() ;a++) {
            if (mBusArrivalPOJOList.get(position).getStationID()
                    .contentEquals(mBusArrivalPOJOListFullDetails.get(a).get(0).getStationID())) {

                if (!mBusArrivalPOJOListFullDetails.get(a).get(0).getPlatformName().contentEquals("null"))
                    if (!((ViewHolder) holder).stationNameTV.getText().toString().contains("::"))
                        ((ViewHolder) holder).stationNameTV.append(" :: "+mBusArrivalPOJOListFullDetails.get(a).get(0).getPlatformName());

                for (int j=0; j< mBusArrivalPOJOListFullDetails.get(a).size() ;j++) {
                    Collections.sort(mBusArrivalPOJOListFullDetails.get(a), new Comparator<BusArrivalPOJO>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(BusArrivalPOJO busArrivalPOJO, BusArrivalPOJO t1) {
                            return busArrivalPOJO.getTimeToArrival() - t1.getTimeToArrival();
                        }
                    });
                }

                Set<String> uniqueBusNamesSet  = new HashSet<>();
                for (int m = 0; m< mBusArrivalPOJOListFullDetails.get(a).size() ;m++) {
                    uniqueBusNamesSet.add(mBusArrivalPOJOListFullDetails.get(a).get(m).getBusName());
                }

                ArrayList<Multimap<String, Integer>> allBusesForParticularStation = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String key: uniqueBusNamesSet) {
                    Multimap<String, Integer> busWithTimes = ArrayListMultimap.create();
                    for (int s=0; s< mBusArrivalPOJOListFullDetails.get(a).size() ;s++) {
                        if (key.contentEquals(mBusArrivalPOJOListFullDetails.get(a).get(s).getBusName())) {
                            busWithTimes.put(key +"::"+ mBusArrivalPOJOListFullDetails.get(a).get(s).getDestinationName()
                                    , mBusArrivalPOJOListFullDetails.get(a).get(s).getTimeToArrival());
                        }
                    }
                    allBusesForParticularStation.add(busWithTimes);
                }

                ((ViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                for (int t=0 ; t< allBusesForParticularStation.size() ;t++) {
                    Multimap<String,  Integer> map = allBusesForParticularStation.get(t);
                    for (String key: map.keySet()) {
                        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(map.get(key));

                        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
                        relativeLayout.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);

                        LinearLayout linearLayoutForBusName = new LinearLayout(mContext);
                        linearLayoutForBusName.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                        final TextView busNameTV = new TextView(mContext);
                        busNameTV.setText(key.split("::")[0]);
                        busNameTV.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-normal", Typeface.NORMAL));
                        busNameTV.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorTextPrimary));

                        final TextView destinationNameTV = new TextView(mContext);
                        destinationNameTV.setText(key.split("::")[1]);
                        destinationNameTV.setTextSize(12);
                        destinationNameTV.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorTextSecondary));

                        linearLayoutForBusName.addView(busNameTV);
                        linearLayoutForBusName.addView(destinationNameTV);

                        LinearLayout linearLayoutForTimes = new LinearLayout(mContext);
                        linearLayoutForTimes.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                        RelativeLayout timeRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
                        timeRelativeLayout.setId(R.id.time_relativeLayout_id);

                        LinearLayout timeArrowLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
                        timeArrowLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                        timeArrowLinearLayout.setId(R.id.time_id);
                        timeArrowLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                        timeArrowLinearLayout.setPadding(6,6,6,6);

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams timeArrowLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        timeArrowLP.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.time_tv);
                        timeArrowLP.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                        timeArrowLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(timeArrowLP);


                        //Recent Time text view
                        TextView timeTV = new TextView(mContext);
                        int timeSec = values.get(0);
                        int timeInMin = Math.round(timeSec / 60);
                        if (timeInMin == 0) {
                            String timeText = "due";
                            timeTV.setText(timeText);
                        } else {
                            String timeInMinText = timeInMin + " min";
                            timeTV.setText(timeInMinText);
                        }
                        timeTV.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.textColorAccent));
                        timeTV.setPadding(0,0,16,0);

                        final TextView remainingTimesTV = new TextView(mContext);
                        remainingTimesTV.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorTextSecondary));
                        remainingTimesTV.setTextSize(11);
                        remainingTimesTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        for (int l=1; l< values.size() && l < 4; l++) {
                            String tempTime;
                            if (l == 3 || l == values.size() - 1) {
                                tempTime = values.get(l) / 60 + " min";
                            }
                            else
                                tempTime = values.get(l)/60 + " min, ";
                            remainingTimesTV.append(tempTime);
                        }

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams remainingTimeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                                (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        remainingTimeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                        remainingTimeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.time_id);
                        remainingTimesTV.setLayoutParams(remainingTimeLayoutParams);

                        timeArrowLinearLayout.addView(timeTV);

                        if (values.size() > 1) {

                            //Down arrow button
                            final ImageView imageButton = new ImageView(mContext);
                            imageButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.arrow_down));

                            if (isRemainingTimesOpen != null) {
                                for (String openedRowKey : isRemainingTimesOpen) {
                                    if (openedRowKey.contains(busNameTV.getText().toString()) &&
                                            openedRowKey.contains(destinationNameTV.getText().toString()) &&
                                            openedRowKey.contains(((ViewHolder) holder).stationNameTV.getText().toString())) {
                                        remainingTimesTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_top);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            timeArrowLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    if (remainingTimesTV.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                                        isRemainingTimesOpen.add(busNameTV.getText().toString()
                                                +destinationNameTV.getText().toString()
                                                +(((ViewHolder) holder).stationNameTV.getText().toString()));
                                        remainingTimesTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);
                                        imageButton.animate().rotation(180).start();

                                    } else {
                                        remainingTimesTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_top);
                                        imageButton.animate().rotation(-180).start();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            timeArrowLinearLayout.addView(imageButton);
                        }

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        layoutParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                        layoutParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                        timeRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);

                        timeRelativeLayout.addView(timeArrowLinearLayout);
                        timeRelativeLayout.addView(remainingTimesTV);


                        View horLine = new View(mContext);
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                1);
                        horLine.setLayoutParams(layoutParams3);
                        horLine.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.horizontal_line));
                        horLine.setPadding(0,5,0,5);

                        relativeLayout.addView(linearLayoutForBusName);
                        relativeLayout.addView(timeRelativeLayout);
                        ((ViewHolder) holder).cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                            }
                        });

                        mLinearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);

                        if (t < uniqueBusNamesSet.size()-1) {
                            mLinearLayout.addView(horLine);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mBusArrivalPOJOList.size();
}

private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView stationNameTV;
    TextView timeToWalkToStation;
    CardView cardView;
    MKLoader progressBar;

    ViewHolder(View view, TextView stationNameTV, TextView timeToWalkToStation, CardView cardView,
               MKLoader progressBar) {
        super(view);
        this.stationNameTV = stationNameTV;
        this.timeToWalkToStation = timeToWalkToStation;
        this.cardView = cardView;
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you solved it yet?

Comment: No. It was many days back. I don't remember properly, but came up with a work around

Answer (score 0):

You are adjusting the UI in the background.

Use the method `onPostExecute()` from AsyncTask to adjust your UI.

Comment: I have been updating the UI in the main thread itself by updating them in getActivity().runOnUiThread() block

Answer (score 0):

In this code, you are not invoking `notifyDataSetChanged()` when adding items to `mBusArrivalPOJOList` (for example, check `getDataFromJson()` for `GetNearbyStops` class) or I am not able to find where you are invoking it. Please make sure that you are invoking `notifyDataSetChanged()` immediately after changing the objects you send to adapter be it adding (one item, multiple items) or removing (one item or multiple items) or clearing.

Comment: I updated my code by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding items to `mBusArrivalPOJOList` . But still the same problem I am facing

Comment: Would you please update code in the question so I can check? Thank you.

Comment: You do not need to put `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside `runOnUiThread()`. The `RecyclerView.Adapter` uses Observable to identify changes and do what's necessary. Please make sure you invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()` immeadiately after you change in both `mButArrivalPOJOList` and `mBusArrivalDetailsPOJOList`.

Comment: Why are you resetting adapter on `RecyclerView` in `GetBusArrivals` task?

Comment: I did that because the views of the items that are visible are not getting updated. So as first few elements are first visible i am updating them by resetting adapter. Its just a temporary workaround for my actual problem.

Comment: I guess then you can remove it and carefully check if you are missing `notifyDataSetChanged()` call after updating the lists.

Comment: My `onBindView()` is getting called for every `notifyDataSetChanged()` call. It is just that the view is not getting updated.